# Adding a uiview on a uiview in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I am passing a view to UITableViewCell from cellForForAtIndex method. I want cell to resize based upon the content of UIView but cell's height is not changing. I have tried to add constraint from coding when I add custom view.
UITableViewCell method:

```
func addContainerView(view:UIView){
    vwContainer.addSubview(view)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: vwContainer, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: vwContainer, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: vwContainer, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: vwContainer, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
}
```

Above code is called from the following code in CellForRowAtIndex:

```
if let rowObj = objData?.itemsArray?[indexPath.row] as? TableViewDataFormat, let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableViewCell, for: indexPath) as? HiltiTableViewCell {
        if let container = rowObj.containerview{
            cell.addContainerView(view: container)
            cell.lblTitle.text = rowObj.cellTitle
        }
        return cell
    }
```

The objective here is to create a custom uitableview in a custom framework where I can pass a UIView and cell should resize based upon the content of the view passed in.

**Edit 1:**
Tried to add content over contentview like following:
cell.contentView.addSubview(container)
but still getting an overlapped view as follows:
[image]

It should have bee 3 different cells, first one with uiview and other 2 with image inside

Comment: You're adding a view on top of the cell, why you expect the cell height to change?

Comment: I tried to add it to content also but still, views are overlapping

Comment: The code you wrote is for overlapping views.

Comment: Try to use StackView and add to view to it. Remember to remove this view on prepareForReuse, because it will be added again and again.

Comment: I can't use stackview here, as there will be a different kind of tablecell here. In addition to custom view, I will also have the option to create a cell on the basis of few predefined templates.

Comment: In my humble opinion `cellForRowAt` should be used to dequeue a cell and provide the cell with basic data, not prepare the view. Have you attempted to set `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension`? Have you considered using `willDisplayCell` tableView delegate method or creating a custom `UITableViewCell` class to configure your view?